# IndexOutOfBoundsException при добавлении элемента в ArrayList

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Если список `reddots`:

```
ArrayList<Red> reddots =  new ArrayList();
```

В него добавляются элементы:

```
class DotListener extends InputListener {
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
        event.getListenerActor().remove();
        float xx = event.getListenerActor().getX();
        float yy = event.getListenerActor().getY();
        int ind = ((int)xx - 46) / 69;
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            Red r = new Red();
            r.setSize(30, 30);
            r.setPosition(xx, yy);
            r.setColor(Color.RED);
            reddots.add(ind, r);
            stage.addActor(r);
        } else {
            Blue b = new Blue();
            b.setSize(30, 30);
            b.setPosition(xx, yy);
            b.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            stage.addActor(b);
        }
        count++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Почему код крашится? Если убрать `reddots.add(ind, r)`, то крашиться не будет. Но мне нужно давать индекс каждой точке.

Классы `Red` и `Blue` наследуются от `Dot`.

Класс `Dot`:

```
class Dot extends Actor { //invisible
    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        Color batchColor = batch.getColor();
        final float r = batchColor.r;
        final float g = batchColor.g;
        final float b = batchColor.b;
        final float a = batchColor.a;
        Color dotColor = getColor();
        batch.setColor(dotColor.r, dotColor.g, dotColor.b, dotColor.a * parentAlpha);
        batch.draw(dotimg, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        batch.setColor(r, g, b, a);
    }
}
```

Ошибка в консоли:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 151
>                     Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 2941
>                     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 0
>                         at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:457)
>                         at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame$DotListener.touchDown(MyGdxGame.java:48)
>                         at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:56)
>                         at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.notify(Actor.java:182)
>                         at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.fire(Actor.java:147)
>                         at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchDown(Stage.java:282)
>                         at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.processEvents(AndroidInput.java:375)
>                         at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:457)
>                         at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1548)
>                         at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1259)
>   E/AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing

Comment: А не равен ли `reddots` случайно `null`?

Comment: @VladD в представленном коде он объявлен вообще за границами класса. Остаётся лишь надеяться, что этот класс `DotListener`  является внутренним классом.

Comment: Чтобы понять, почему код крашится, стоит для начала проанализировать stacktrace исключения. Добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: DotListener - внутренний класс , reddots - поле главного

Comment: @Regent что такое StackTrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаёте пустой список:

```
ArrayList<Red> reddots = new ArrayList();
```

Размер (`size`) по умолчанию у него `0`.

Когда вы пытаетесь добавить элемент в список на определённую позицию, происходит такая проверка:

```
if (index > size || index < 0)
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
```

Так как `index` в вашем случае равен `9` (судя по stacktrace), а размер - `0`, то в итоге пробрасывается исключение.

Вариантов решения проблемы в данной ситуации как минимум два:

1. Добавлять элементы не на конкретный индекс, а в конец списка:

   ```
   reddots.add(r);
   ```
2. Если всё же нужно добавлять на определённый индекс, то стоит позаботиться о размере списка при его создании:

   ```
   int dotsCount = 1000;
   Red[] dummy = new Red[dotsCount];
   ArrayList<Red> reddots = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dummy));
   ```

На всякий случай уточню зачем городить такой код:

- Если просто создать `ArrayList`, задав ему `initialCapacity`, то `size` его по-прежнему будет `0` и `IndexOutOfBoundsException` снова появится.
- Если сделать `List<Red> reddots = Arrays.asList(dummy);`, то при попытке добавить элемент в список будет проброшено `UnsupportedOperationException`.